# Bounds for hypothesis testing with non-normal distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric, normality-assumption, rule-of-thumb

After doing randomized experiment with two variants (AB tests), I want to do **hypothesis testing without the normal distribution assumption** to compare their means. Since the samples sizes are different, and there the variances is not assumed to be equal either that would be a [Welch's t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test).

Since the test statistics is the mean and thanks to the Central limit theorem the non-normality should not be an issue provided that that samples are "sufficiently large".

"Sufficiently large" is not very precise. One can find rules of thumb like *n1 + n2 > 40*, but that does not hold, for example if the means are very small.

**Are there known bounds on the t-statistics or the p-value** given the sample sizes, means and standard deviations, or even with also skewness and kurtosis?